# my form in Div is unclickable

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a wordpress theme and I've added a client login div to the header...

For some reason the boxes to enter the email address and password cannot be typed in however I can click the submit button.

Have I missed something?

This is the CSS in use:

```
.art-header {
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 290px;
  background-image: url('images/object617858221.png'), url('images/header.jpg');
  background-position: 70px 182px, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  z-index: auto !important;
}

.art-shapes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}

.client-login {
  width: 214px;
  margin: 100px 10px 0 0;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

This is the code that makes up the header area

```
<header class="art-header"><?php get_sidebar('header'); ?>
<div class="client-login">
<div class="client-header">Client Login</div>
<form method="post" action="https://secure.mysite.it/dologin.php">
<input type="text" name="username" style="width: 200px; margin-bottom:5px;" value="Enter Email Address" /><br />
<input type="password" name="password" style="width: 200px; margin-bottom:5px;" /><br />
<input class="art-button" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</div></header>
```

My site (http://goo.gl/YcugjZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not checked out your form, but this is what i can tell your from experience.

Often when stuff is not "clickable" or "focusable" there are some sort of element "on top of it". This often happens when you have negative margins, absolute positioning or other funky stuff.

See this picture:
[image: Annoying divs]

The red box is the "conflicting" div, and prevents the textboxes from being clicked.

The easiest way to find out if this is the case, is to simply right click the textbox and then go to "Inspect element" or similar (depending on browser). If you could provide a link or fiddle to the login-box, that would be fantastic.

---

Update. OPs site [here](http://goo.gl/YcugjZ).

The problem i describe above is indeed the problem.

On the site, you can find the following

```
<div class="art-shapes">

</div>
```

The CSS-rulesets are the following:

```
.art-shapes {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

When inspecting, you can see that it is indeed covering the the inputs

[image: div covering inputs]

My suggestion is just to remove the `div.artshapes`-element, since it does not actually do anything.

Comment: Hi All,
I've just added a link to my site (http://goo.gl/YcugjZ)
I cannot see any invisible elements sitting over it other than the whole header section.

Comment: I was correct! Inspecting "the input" shows the `div` with the class `art-shapes` are covering your inputs. It does not seem to do much at the current state. Consider removing it?

Comment: Perfect! I've got no idea why that was there, I think if I make the header clickable then its used!
I've just removed it! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Next time, just use chrome's inspector and inspect it; it took me 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I created a working jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/x0ybkpn8/

I am able to click into and modify the input field values without changing your original code.

Without seeing the actual page or code that doesn't work, it will be difficult to guess what the issue is.

Perhaps an invisible element is overlaid on top of the input fields rendering the user unable to click them.

I would inspect the surrounding elements to see if there are any values with a greater `z-index` than your input fields.

Comment: This is what i meant in my answer; there is not enough information @Totally Tech ID's post to provide a more elaborate answer. I also did a fiddle.